# Trying to add and display a sum of values from a ListBox... getting error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Tags: c#, arrays, sum

I'm trying to get the sum of all values in the Listbox and I want to display the result in a textbox. when I run the program and click the button, I get the following error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

```
    private void readButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Harra\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\File Reader\Sales.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            displayListBox.Items.Add(line);
            counter++;
        }
        {

            int intTotal = 0;
            int intCounter;
            double dblAdd;

            for (intCounter = 0; intCounter <= displayListBox.Items.Count - 1; intCounter++)

            {
                intTotal += Convert.ToInt32(displayListBox.Items[intCounter];
            }

            dblAdd = (double)intTotal;

            //trying to display total to textbox
            totalTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:F}", dblAdd);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comments and more details, I think this should work:

```
private void readButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Harra\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\File Reader\Sales.txt");
    double dblAdd = 0;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        displayListBox.Items.Add(line);
        dblAdd += Convert.ToDouble(line);
    }
    totalTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:F}", dblAdd);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response!
I'm still getting an error message: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: Well, are your listbox items not integers, then? Give an example of your listbox item values (lines from the sales.txt file)

Comment: Here are two examples: 1245.67, 1189.55

Comment: ok, these are decimal values and can't be converted to int. Do you care about the decimal spaces in your sum?

Comment: I've amended my answer

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help!